# Haskell - Find the element

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, predicate

I'm new to haskell. My exercise is to write a predicate that checks whether an element is present in a list. But I have to solve using a linearly recursive process WITHOUT pattern matching.

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM y (x:xs)
 | null xs = False
 | y == x = True
 | otherwise = isPresentRecNonPM y xs
```

That's my code, But i can't find my mistake. Can you help me. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you input, what does the function output, what did you expect instead, or if it doesn't compile what is the error message? Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: `(x:xs)` is pattern matching by the way so as per your description it's not allowed.

Comment: You haven't defined `isPresentRecNonPM []`. `null xs` only checks if the *tail* of the argument is empty; you are prematurely returning `False`.

Comment: You did not handle the case `isPresentRecNonPM 4 []`. Your check for `null` checks that `xs` is empty, so it only handles cases like `isPresentRecNonPM 4 (5:[])`. I recommend you turn on warnings compiling with `-Wall`, which makes GHC report these kinds of mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You are prematurely returning `False`, as `null xs` checks if the *tail* of the non-empty list argument is empty.

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM _ xs | null xs = False
isPresentRecNonPM y (x:xs)
 | y == x = True
 | otherwise = isPresentRecNonPM y xs
```

Since you are supposed to avoid pattern matching, I suspect you aren't supposed to use `(x:xs)`, either, and use `head` and `tail` explicitly after confirming the argument is not empty.

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM y xs
 | null xs = False
 | head xs == y = True
 | otherwise = isPresentRecNonPM y (tail xs)
```

(If they are *really* serious about not using pattern matching, you need to avoid the irrefutable patterns `y` and `xs` as well and define the function in point-free style.)

Answer (score 2):

Well you *are* using pattern matching. Indeed, you use `(x:xs)`, which is a pattern for a list type. You should use `xs` to match with the entire list, so:

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM y xs
 | null xs = False
 | y == head xs = True
 | otherwise = isPresentRecNonPM y (tail xs)
```

You can further simplify this with:

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM y = go
  where go xs
          | null xs = False
          | y == head xs = True
          | otherwise = go (tail xs)
```

we can write this shorter with:

```
isPresentRecNonPM :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isPresentRecNonPM y = go
  where go xs = not (null xs) && (y == head xs || go (tail xs))
```

that being said, since `head` and `tail` are non-total functions, it is often better to work with pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

You're not handling the empty list, due to your mistaken use of pattern matching.

I'm fairly sure that you're not supposed to do any separate case analysis at all, but instead think about the conditions under which the predicate is true and write a single logical expression.

This predicate is true if and only if

- the list is not empty, *and*
- what you're looking for is either the first element *or* it is found in the tail of the list.

In code,

```
isPresentRecNonPM  y xs = not (null xs) 
                          && (y == head xs || isPresentRecNonPM  y (tail xs))
```